# Magic Square Arrays Giving Garbage Data

Tags: c++, arrays, magic-square

I'm writing a C++ program that will determine magic squares from a text file. While the size of the matrix prints fine, all my data inside is printed as the same garbage data. Example:

```
Matrix = 3

-858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460

This is a magic square!
```

Code is posted below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int readSquare(int matrix1[][40]);
void printMatrix(int matrix1[][40], int matrixSize1);
void  checkValid(int matrix1[][40], int matrixSize1);

int main()
{
    int matrix1[40][40];
    //call function to open file and load matrix array with matrix found in file
    int matrixSize = readSquare(matrix1);

    //call function to output
    if (matrixSize)
    {
        printMatrix(matrix1, matrixSize);

        //call function to verify if square is a magic square
        checkValid(matrix1, matrixSize);
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to continue." << endl << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int readSquare(int matrix1[][40])
{
    ifstream input;
    //open file
    input.open("Prog2Input.txt");
    int matrix[1600];
    int test[1600];
    //create object to read file




    //counter
    int rows = 1, num, size = 1;
    while (input >> num)
    {
        if (test[num] == 0)
        {
            matrix[rows] = num;
            test[num] = num;
            rows++;
            if (size < num)
                size = num;
        }
        else
            cout << "The Magic Square had an error." << endl;
    }
    rows--;
    num = 3;
    while (num*num < size)
        num++;


    //load matrix in array
    int z = 1;
    for (int x = 1; x <= num; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y <= num; y++)
        {
            matrix1[x][y] = matrix[z];
            z++;
        }
    }
    //close file
    input.close();

    return num;


}

void printMatrix(int matrix1[][40], int matrixSize1)
{
    cout << "Matrix\n\n";
    cout << "Matrix Size = " << matrixSize1 << endl << endl;

    // Dislay Matrix
    for (int x = 1; x <= matrixSize1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y <= matrixSize1; y++)
        {
            if (matrix1[x][y] < 10)
                cout << " ";
            cout << matrix1[x][y] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void checkValid(int matrix1[][40], int matrixSize1)
{
    int Row_Total = 0, Total;
    bool Square = true;
    // Get # for top r
    for (int x = 1; x <= matrixSize1; x++)
        Row_Total += matrix1[1][x];

    // Read  row compare to top
    for (int x = 1; x <= matrixSize1; x++)
    {
        Total = 0; // Reset variable for next row
        for (int y = 1; y <= matrixSize1; y++)
        {
            Total += matrix1[x][y];
        }
        if (Total != Row_Total)
            Square = false;
    }

    // Read  colum compare to row
    for (int y = 1; y <= matrixSize1; y++)
    {
        Total = 0; // Reset # for next column
        for (int x = 1; x <= matrixSize1; x++)
        {
            Total += matrix1[x][y];
        }
        if (Total != Row_Total)
            Square = false;
    }

    Total = 0; // Reset #

               // Read diagonal top left to low right
    for (int x = 1; x <= matrixSize1; x++)
    {
        Total += matrix1[x][x];
    }
    if (Total != Row_Total)
        Square = false;


    // Read diagonal top right to bottom left

    int y = 1;
    Total = 0; // Reset variable
    for (int x = matrixSize1; x >0; x--)
    {
        Total += matrix1[y][x];
        y++;
    }
    if (Total != Row_Total)
        Square = false;


    if (Square)
    cout << "\n" << "Magic Square!" << "\n\n";

    else
    cout << "\n" << "Not A Magic Square." << "\n\n";
}
```

Anything obvious that is prevent the normal print out? I've looked up plenty of examples but none seem to fix my specific issue. Thanks for any pointers or advice.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I suggest you use `std::array` or `std::vector` which are bounds checked on good debuggers and may detect any bugs you've missed. If you use vectors you can also specify the size at runtime and not limit your program to an arbitrary size of square.

Comment: Your test array isn't initialized and will be filled with random data.

Comment: Unrelated: You're going to save yourself a lot of head-scratching in the future if you simply embrace the fact that arrays in C++ and C are zero-base indexed.

Comment: I would say the most likely reason is that you are failing to open your file. Add the following code, replace `input.open("Prog2Input.txt");` with `if (!input.open("Prog2Input.txt")) cout << "file open failed!!\n";` It always good practise to check if files open correctly, they're too many ways this can fail.

Comment: What should I initialize my test to? zero?

Comment: Progress? Initializing to zero displays all zeros. But still not my file's data!

Comment: I've been using one but I still can't get it to work exactly.